# Bottom Tabbed Bar With Customised Tab Menu

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am trying to get a Circular Icon of my Application Logo right in middle of tabbed bar menu's, I have 5 Tab Menu's where the third one i want it to look like this

[image: this]
trying to get this on Android & Ios

i have tried custom rendering by removing the padding but still not able to get the desired result, i found one solution updating icon using SetTabIcons Method but this method does not get trigger when we are working with bottom tabbed bar in Android, please suggest me something which can help me to get this for both android & Ios

Comment: Better to open this issue here you may get satisfactory answer https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem here, i am not sure how to get that big button overflowing the tabbar but however have a look at this

> https://devlinduldulao.pro/how-to-create-bottom-navigation-bar-in-xamarin-forms/

That's an open source project and the source code is linked at the bottom of page, you can tweak the animation (which i like very much) and use a customrenderer to render the center icon over a circle.

Have a look if that helps you in any way! :)

Comment: i already went through that sample and tried to tweak that but could not find the solution

Comment: well, Let us know if you come up with a solution, also i'll keep a hook here and come back if i find something more appropriate.